# Why doesn't the Grapical display of contributions display correctly?

Tags: civicontribute

On the CiviContribute Dashboard you can display the contributions over a time period as a bar chart, and the display is split between the monthly data and a separate block for the total received. However, if the total is more than £10,000 the block is not wide enough to properly display the axis numbers beyond 4 digits plus the currency. I have looked at the code for the page and this block is set to 150px wide by 250px height, but I don't know the code well enough to find out where to change this value. Can anyone help me with this, so I can edit it myself, and/or can you change the core code to give a width of at least 180px so the axis is displayed correctly?

Comment: Have tried this on both Firefox and Microsoft Edge (Win 10) with the same effect when first opening the dashboard, BUT on both browsers, if you change the viewing magnification, the axis labels DO get displayed correctly, but without the currency symbol. This is more than just a field width problem, I think, something to do with the way it is displayed?

Comment: I have now put some more contribution data in and I now find that the second graph actually expands to show previous years as well as the current year's totals. However, y-axis now appears to display numbers correctly but without currency symbol and there are no labels at all on the x-axis.

Comment: Any luck with this? I am having this issue